# PowerShell script Scheduled Task change local user password value based on set password

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, change-password

I am working on a PowerShell script that would run in a Task Scheduler.
The way I want it to work is:

Default value is set to force user to change password at next logon:
`net user su /logonpasswordchg:yes`
[image: user must change password at next logon]

Now the code would be something like:

$password = Azerty123!
if $password is different from $password
switch password from "user must change password at next logon" to "Password never expires"
else leave value to change password at next logon

After multiple tests I figured that the 2 following values would need to be switched based on the current password

1. `Set-LocalUser -Name "su" -PasswordNeverExpires:$true`
2. `Set-LocalUser -Name "su" -PasswordNeverExpires:$false`
3. `net user su /logonpasswordchg:yes`
4. `net user su /logonpasswordchg:no`

Basically the script is deployed with Intune, creates a Task Scheduler, it would check the password value every day one per day, if the password has been changed, the password value is changed to never expire, as long as the password as never been changed, leave it as change password at next logon.
Can anyone help me on this ? sorry for my clumsy explanations

Comment: How would you know the password for user 'su' ?

Comment: I put the password in a variable while creating a local account.
So the first time the code run it's always the same password, once the user connects, he's prompted to change the password.
If the password has been changed before the next check, then it doesn't match anymore so it becomes set to password never expire.
Does that makes sense ?

Comment: Do you have any other users that require password to expire? As an alternative approach you could use local GPO? Local Computer Policy –> Computer Configuration –> Windows Settings –> Security Settings –> Account Policies –> Password PolicySet ‘Maximum password age’ to ‘0’

Comment: Unfortunately no, the end goal being to have this script deployed in an Intunewin package through Intune.
Unless there's a way to proceed a similar way in Intune with the GPO you described, that may do the trick but I didn't find anything on this.

Comment: I haven't dealt much with InTune, but seems like you can do Local GPO settings there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/administrative-templates-windows. Alternatively you can call this in a 1 off script `net accounts /maxpwage:0`. But policy approach would be more certain in my opinion

Comment: @andr3yk thank you for your response, it actually helped me a lot, I used a net accounts command as you suggested and it did the job. Can you post it as an actual response to the topic so I can set this question as solved ? Best.

Comment: @LeanneKami, no problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach could be to change the password expiry setting globally on Windows system.
This will apply to all users and can be done prior specific user changed their password. It can be accomplished by running following command:

```
net accounts /maxpwage:0
```

Note: check comments section to the answer for in depth discussion of other approaches